# $\aleph_1$ and $\omega_1$, what are they?

Tags: cardinals, real-numbers, ordinals

Sorry for my ignorant question but..

I understand that some sources says that $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the real numbers (ℝ) 
because  In set theory

$$\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0} $$

and the power set of $\aleph_0$ is $\aleph_1$,

so $\mathfrak{c} = \aleph_1$.

But what I don't understand is that some sources define it as the cardinality of 
the set of all countable ordinal numbers, called $ω_1$.

So what is $\aleph_1$ really?

What is $ω_1$? Is it the order type of the real numbers?

And if it's not how can we find the order type of the real numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\aleph_1$ is a cardinal number, and $\omega_1$ is an ordinal number. They are used for different things, but they are very related. One might even be so bold as to say that they are the same set, only used in different contexts.

Cardinal numbers are used to count how large sets are. Whether $\aleph_1$ corresponds to the size of the set of real numbers is something that one in most cases needs to *assume* specifically as an axiom; it is, for instance, not provable from ZFC whether $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ are the same. The assumption that they *are* the same is called the *continuum hypothesis*.

If you want to go one step further and stipulate that $\aleph_{n+1} = 2^{\aleph_n}$ for any $n$ that makes sense, then that is called the *generalised* continuum hypothesis. In any case, there are no cardinals between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$.

Ordinal numbers, on the other hand, are about ordering (as the name implies), rather than counting. The first infinite ordinal is called $\omega$ or $\omega_0$, and the first *uncountable* ordinal is called $\omega_1$. However, between those two there are a *lot* of different ordinals (there are many different ways to arrange a countably infinite set of objects, even indistinguishable ones). In fact, there are $\aleph_1$ many of them.

The ordinals classify all possible *well-orders*, and while the real numbers are usually totally ordered, whether there exists a well-order to them, and thus an ordinal order type, is again something that is unprovable and must be assumed as an axiom. It's worth noting that the C in ZFC *does* imply that there exists a well-ordering of the reals, but it says nothing about what order type that might be, and it does not say what the *cardinality* of $\mathfrak c$ is. Only that it exists as an $\aleph$.

Comment: Excellent answer (+1), except for a couple of oddities in the last sentence. First, $\omega_\omega$ is impossible; [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) tells us that $2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot be the sum of countably many smaller cardinals. Also, no point in mentioning $\omega_1+5;$ clearly, a set has a well-ordering of type $\omega_1+5$ if and only if it has a well-ordering of type $\omega_1.$

Comment: @bof I suspected I was off there, yes.

Comment: The notion of "order type" does not depend on the ordering being a well-ordering, the order type of $\mathbb{R}$ is just the way the reals are ordered, it has no name involving $\omega$.

Comment: A small correction: for those who use von Neumann cardinals, $\omega_1$ is both an ordinal *and* a cardinal number. For many of us the cardinality of $\omega$ is routinely written $\omega$, the cardinality of $\Bbb R$ is $2^\omega$, and the alephs are an unnecessary alternative notation.

Comment: @Christian: Very true, though I have seen it called $\theta$, just as $\eta$ is commonly used to denote the order type of the rationals.

Comment: @Arthur: Thank you very much sir for that excellent answer, but I have one more question, if you will be so kind to answer it......if (aleph1) isn't necessarily the cardinality of ℝ....and ω1 isn't necessarily the order type of ℝ.... why do they exist??

Comment: @TalalSharaa Because they are the first uncountable cardinal and the first uncountable ordinal, respectively. We can prove their existence the following way: Any countable ordinal may be embedded in an order-preserving way into $\Bbb Q$, so certain elements of $\mathscr P(\Bbb Q)$ are well-ordered under the usual $<$. Now, for each countable ordinal $\alpha$, let $X_\alpha \subseteq \mathscr P(\Bbb Q)$ be the set of all such embeddings of $\alpha$. Then the set of all $X_\alpha\in \mathscr P(\mathscr P (\Bbb Q))$ is a well-ordered, uncountable set, and it is order isomorphic to $\omega_1$.

Answer (score 2):

"and the power set of aleph null is aleph1"

That is wrong, although I suspect many math professors think this is true.

The cardinality of the power set of a set whose cardinality is $\aleph_0$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$.  Generally, the cardinality of the set of all functions from a set of cardinality $a$ into a set of cardinality $b$ is $b^a$.

Ever since the time of Cantor, $\aleph_1$ has been defined to be the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals. It can be proved that no cardinality is between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$.  Cantor conjectured that $\aleph_1= 2^{\aleph_0}$, but he could not prove that.

$\omega_1$ is the set of all countable ordinals, or "ordinal numbers.  The "ordinal numbers" begin with the finite numbers $0,1,2,3,\ldots$.  The order type of this set is $\omega$, the smallest infinite ordinal.  This is followed by $\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,\ldots$, and all of these by $\omega2=\omega+\omega$ (not to be confused with $2\omega$, which is the same as $\omega$.  After $\omega+\omega + \omega+\cdots$ there is a smallest ordinal, and they go on from there.  The set of all countably infinite ordinals is uncountable, and its cardinality is $\aleph_1$.

Comment: I was pretty certain that at least the 1st edition of Kenneth Kunen's Set Theory (from 1980) used $2\omega$ for $\omega + \omega$, but I checked my copy of the second edition (2011), and it does use $\omega 2$. Do you know how established that is, exactly?

Comment: @Arthur : I think the idea is that $2\omega$ means $\omega$ copies of $2$, thus $2+2+2+\cdots$, where each $2$ is a linearly ordered set with two elements, and the order of addition is the order in which the objects appear; whereas $\omega2$ means $2$ copies of $\omega$: i.e. $\omega+\omega$, where they appear in that order: $0,1,2,3,\ldots$ followed by $0,1,2,3,\ldots$. The first one, $2\omega$, is the same as $\omega$, since you have infinitely many things and each has only finitely many predecessors. In $\omega+\omega$, some members of the ordered set have infinitely many predecessors.

Comment: Since that convention, with a non-commutative addition and a non-commutative multiplication, makes sense, I suspect it is quite widespread.  However, I am not familiar with current research literature in this area. $\qquad$

Comment: Using $\omega 2$ for $\omega + \omega$ does make multiplication and addition work somewhat similarily (in both cases you may cancel small ordinals on the left if there is a big ordinal on the right). However, I would like to note that there is no _objective_ reason why $2\omega$ can't be the one to mean "two copies of $\omega$". Also, I think it just looks _wrong_ to write numbers after the letters. It looks like someone forgot a `^`. But that's just my personal opinion. Whatever is, is.

Comment: @Arthur The notation whereby $\omega2=\omega+\omega$ and $2\omega=\omega$ goes all the way back to [Cantor](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0049&DMDID=dmdlog24).

Comment: @Arthur Since $2\alpha$ are $\alpha2$ and different, **both** expressions must be available. You may choose which one of them denotes $\alpha+\alpha,$ but you can't avoid "writing a number after a letter."

Comment: @bof I never said we could avoid it. But it would change how often it appears. Just as we have decided that multiplication takes priority over addition, and exponentiation over multiplication to avoid having to write parentheses everywhere, like $(5(x^2)) + (3x) - 2$. That doesn't mean that we can _avoid_ parentheses, but we have chosen the convension that gives the least of them. In the same way, if we had chosen $2\omega$ to mean $\omega + \omega$, then that wouldn't avoid having to write $\alpha2$ from time to time, but it would happen much less frequently.